# Developing UI in Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, user-interface

I am trying to develop a game using Unity, and I am in the step of developing some UI. I am going to need a player frame (to show the avatar of the active player in my turn based game), an inventory, and a settings button, with its setting screen.

The player frame thing was easy: I placed a Canvas, and an image. But, I want the inventory screen to appear when that frame is clicked. So, I created another Canvas, placed a plane inside, set a background for the inventory and a button to close it. The inventory panel is shown, but when I click the close button I receive an error. My code:

```
private void Awake()
{
    canvas = GameObject.Find("Canvas");
    inventoryPanel = GameObject.Find("InventoryPanel");
    inventoryPanel.gameObject.SetActive(false);
    this.raycaster = canvas.GetComponent<GraphicRaycaster>();
}
```

When I detect a click in UI component:

```
if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
    {
        PointerEventData pointerData = new PointerEventData(EventSystem.current);
        List<RaycastResult> results = new List<RaycastResult>();

        //Raycast using the Graphics Raycaster and mouse click position
        pointerData.position = Input.mousePosition;
        this.raycaster.Raycast(pointerData, results);
        for(int i = 0; i < results.Count; i++)
            {
                print("Pulsada UI: "+results[i].gameObject.name);
                if (results[i].gameObject.name.Equals("Playerframe"))
                {
                    inventoryPanel.SetActive(true);
                }
                if(results[i].gameObject.name.Equals("Closeinventorybutton"))
                {
                    inventoryPanel.SetActive(false);
                }
            }
}
```

Of course, the raycaster is cast from the first canvas, where the player frame is, the inventory is in ANOTHER canvas, and raycaster is null.

I tried to put the inventory screen in the first canvas, and get its reference this way:

```
inventoryPanel=canvas.gameObject.Find("InventoryPanel");
```

But seems like I cannot do that.

Do I need to create a separate canvas for any UI object in my screen, and get a separate raycaster from every canvas? The same canvas for all the UI components? if so, how can I get references to the different components?

I am having trouble finding tutorials that go further than "A button and a health bar". In other words, how to create a complex UI? A good tutorial would be fine.

Comment: It depends - you can just create a single canvas and put all your UI into the same canvas but arrange related groups into parent/child hierarchies using panels/gameobjects. Just hide/show these based on whether you want the menu open/closed

Comment: The other query I have is why not use the standard UI components so that you don't need to write code to raycast to your components? I know it's not a lot of bother to raycast, but there are button components you can just use `OnClick` events on which might save you a bit of time.

Comment: Its ok in the case of buttons, but not all UI components are buttons. I could do that for them, but I think it could spread code a bit. The way I am planning to do it, everything UI-related would be in the same place.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need one canvas, you can use panels if you want to visually/hierarchically section off parts of your UI.

Edit: easiest way to get a reference to an object

```
public GameObject inventoryPanel;
```

in the inspector, you can drag and drop from the top left hierarchy into the script the inventory panel. Other options

```
GameObject.FindWithTag("TagName");
```

is a good one when you want to reference a component use

```
inventoryPanel.GetComponent<componentType>().variableofcomponent..
```

Comment: How can a get a reference to inventoryPanel?